# .htaccess through error "404 Not Found error was encountered"

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have set code in .htaccess file as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.in/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

home page open well but other pages shows error:

**The requested URL /catalog/product was not found on this server.**
**Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

THANKS in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are all out of order. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.in/$1 [R=301,L]

# Do not redirect existing files/dirs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# Redirect everything else to index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```